# Unresolved Reference - Python

Tags: python

I have a function that takes a string input. I want to count no of times a string occurs in the input.

Example, I have a string cars = "Toyota, Honda, Toyota, BMW, Toyota"

I want a function that returns no of times a string occur

```
toyota_count = 0
honda_count = 0
BMW_count = 0

def count_cars(cars):
    if "toyota" in cars:
        toyota_count += 1
    if "honda" in cars:
        honda_count += 1
```

But this gives me error on toyota_count in the function, it says "Unresolved reference toyota_count"

Comment: Please copy the **full traceback** of your error. Don't type it by hand. There is no "Unresolved reference toyota_count" error in Python; you get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'toyota_count' referenced before assignment` instead.

Comment: In addition, please add sample input and what output you expect based on that input. Don't leave us to guess if `str.count()` would help here.

Answer (score 2):

Its because toyota_count is global.
Either define the variable inside your method (preferred) or specify it inside your methot as global like so:

```
def myfunc():
  gobal toyota_count
```

***EDIT***

You can also just use `cars.count("Toyota")` to get the total number of substrings in a string.

Comment: `cars.count()` can give you an integer greater than 1 and requires scanning the whole string, always. `in` only needs to find the string *once*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: In the OP: _I want to count no of times a string occurs in the input_. Sounds to me they want the total number, not just one occurence.

Comment: Ah, yes, if they want to count the number of times per `cars` string, then yes, use `.count()`. Pity they didn't give an example of what `cars` could look like and what the expected output would be...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your strings don't overlap, just use the string `count()` method. Whilst this isn't uber-efficient (three calls to `count()` and therefore 3 searches) it fits your described use case.

```
cars = "Toyota, Honda, Toyota, BMW, Toyota"
toyota_count = cars.count("Toyota")
honda_count = cars.count("Honda")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
toyota_count = 0
honda_count = 0
BMW_count = 0

def count_cars(cars):
    global toyota_count
    toyota_count = cars.count('Toyota')


count_cars("Toyota, Honda, Toyota, BMW, Toyota")
print (toyota_count)
```